# OpenCV functions are undefined when building packages for ROS, how do I add `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` to catkin build?

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

I have some problems with getting OpenCV-3.1.0 working (directly) with `catkin build`. I am trying to build a workspace of the TIAGo Simulation, but I get errors.

When I build a test file (containing opencv functions) with g++ and flags I have no problems:

`g++ -o test test.cpp ´pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs´`

If I don´t use the flags I get errors:

`g++ -o test test.cpp`

output:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

The same is happening when I´m building the TIAGo Simulation workspace that uses OpenCV when using catkin build.

Trying to build the TIAGo simulation:

```
catkin build
```

output (one of the errors):

```
look_to_point.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
```

So since the errors are quite similar I think it could be solved by adding the equivalent of `´pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs´` to `catkin build`. Since I am quite unexperienced with ROS, catkin, and CMake I don´t know how to accomplish this. 
If anyone wants to point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It's Better To Use CMake To Build The Packages For ROS (Even When You Have a Single Source file) And the Easiest way to do That Is The Command `catkin_create_package` (Might Be Different In Your ROS Distro) And Adding all The Libraries In The `CMakeList.txt` and `Package.xml` That The Command Generates(Almost Everything is Commented Out At The Start) So That Later On You Can Find And Use It In Your ROS Environment.

Here The Link To [ROS Wiki Page For Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage)

And Here's An Example That I Used back Then When I had less Experience With Catkin [In Github](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/catkin/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/CMakeLists.txt)

Answer (score 0):

It eventually turned out to be OpenCV version problem.

Before I found out it was a version problem I tried to add the OpenCV library to every package that needed it by writing it in every CMakeList.txt (there were multiple packages).